# jQuery date formatting to YYYY-MM-DD from conventional form

Tags: javascript, jquery

My jQuery date-picker is outputting something like this:

> junio 6, 2018 (or june 6, 2018)

I would like to convert this like `06-06-2018` or `2018-06-06` or this format: `YYYY-MM-DD`.

I have searched on SO but didn't find a solution for this. This is something new to me.

I tried the following:

```
Jan == 01,
Feb == 02,
...
```

But couldn't find a solution yet.

Comment: What you have tried post ur code

Answer (score 3):

### You can check this

```js
$(function() {
  $("#datepicker").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
```

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using `moment.js`.  It makes tasks like this very easy:

```js
d = 'june 6, 2018'
d2 = 'june 16, 2018'
d3 = 'apr 16, 2018'
console.log(moment(d, 'MMMM DD, YYYY').format('YYYY-MM-DD'))
console.log(moment(d2, 'MMMM DD, YYYY').format('YYYY-MM-DD'))
console.log(moment(d3, 'MMMM DD, YYYY').format('YYYY-MM-DD'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.20.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Although this works in most cases, I believe OP is actually using the jQuery date-picker and thus setting an option on the UI component (as it's available) may be the easiest solution. I too would recommend Moment whenever possible.

Comment: How can i use spanish locale with it?

Comment: Check out https://cdnjs.com/libraries/moment.js/ For the various locales

Comment: but when d is d = `june 16, 2018` or `apr 16, 2018` it does not work

Comment: But in my case some dates are showing invalid and some dates are ok..why?